# How can I create a new unique data frame

Tags: python

I am trying to common and unique values from different years and create a new data frame with only those common values for all the years.

The year is a column in my data frame and I have already sorted df according to the year and now I want to pick only those companies name that are common in those 20 years.

```
df9 = df8.sort_values(['pfy', 'bookvalue'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('pfy')
df10 = df9.head(5)
df10.head(30)
```

[Df10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLbdN.png)

Comment: Can you show the contents of df10 to get an idea of how the data looks like.

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates()` returns distinct rows.

Comment: Hi @abhilb, I have added the 'df10' picture. you can click df10 above to take a look at the data frame